# How do I reconcile the Chrome DevTools / HAR Time column?

Tags: google-chrome-devtools

When I load a HAR into Chrome dev tools, I see this.

[image: chrome dev tools]

`my-first-helm-plugin` loaded in 15ms and `style.css` loaded in 24ms.

When I open the HAR and inspect the JSON I see:

```
# my-first-helm-plugin
"time": 15.927000000374392

# style.css
"time": 26.79199998965487
```

I could explain the output of the `time` of `my-first-helm-plugin` if they were rounding it down to an int. But by that logic `style.css` should be `26` not `24`?

Further confusing the issue is when I open the "Timings" tab in devtools for `my-first-helm-plugin` I see `17.86ms` which doesn't match anything?

[image: my-first-helm-plugin timings]

Same with `style.css`. Timings shows `24`.

[Google's own HAR analyzer](https://toolbox.googleapps.com/apps/har_analyzer/) does not agree with dev tools (but does agree with the JSON):

[image: har analyzer]

Comment: 17.68 - 2.85 (in-queue time) = 14.83 i.e. 15ms of pure network time. As for analyzer, it includes the in-queue time. It's debatable which one is more useful for a developer.